# Send to a called email address

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress admin I have a Agent input screen, this is that taxonomy:

```html
//agent taxonomy
$options[] =  array(
 'id'          => _WSH()->set_term_key('property_agent'),
 'types'       => array('property_agent'),
 'title'       => __('property Category Settings', SH_NAME),
 'priority'    => 'high',
 'template'    => 
   array(
     array(
      'type' => 'upload',
      'name' => 'agent_img',
      'label' => __( 'Agent image', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'facebook_link',
      'label' => __( 'Facebook Link', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'twitter_link',
      'label' => __( 'Twitter Link', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'instagram_link',
      'label' => __( 'Instagram Link', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'google_plus_link',
      'label' => __( 'Google Plus Link', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'linked_in_link',
      'label' => __( 'Linked in Link', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'phone',
      'label' => __( 'Phone Number', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     array(
      'type' => 'textbox',
      'name' => 'email',
      'label' => __( 'Email', SH_NAME ),
     ),
     
    ),
);
```

I have built a contact form:
[image]

I am presently calling the highlighted email from above script with:

```html
<p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:11px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p>
```

Presently my contact form when submitted is going to the Admin email with this line of script:

```html
$to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
```

What I am trying to change is instead of going to the Admin's email go to the called Agent's email that is highlighted. Being there will be different agents, I need the email to be sent to the called email from very above script.

Complete Script that fetches Admin taxonomy:

```html
<!--======= AGENT DETAILS =========-->
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
       <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(_sh_get_attachment_id_from_src(sh_set($meta1, 'agent_img')), '270x288');?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
       <?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_id(), 'property_agent', array("fields" => "names")); ?>
       <h5><?php echo implode( ', ', (array)$term_list );?></h5>
       <!--======= SOCIAL ICONS =========-->
       <ul class="social_icons">
        <li class="facebook"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'facebook_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'twitter_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <!--<li class="googleplus"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'google_plus_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>-->
        <!--<li class="linkedin"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'linked_in_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>-->
        <li class="instagram"><a href="<?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'instagram_link');?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
       <p><?php $description = $agents_term[0]->description; echo $description;?></p>

       <!--======= AGENT INFOR =========-->
       <ul class="agent-info">
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'phone');?> </p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span style='font-size:11px'><?php echo sh_set($meta1, 'email');?></span></p>
        </li>
        <li>
         <p><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <?php printf( esc_html__('Listed %s Properties', 'realtor'), sh_set(sh_set($agents_term, 0 ) , 'count' ) );?> </p>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: What does `sh_set()` do? Is it your own function?

Comment: Hi Reza, thanks for replying. sh_get is what the theme author is using can see it in above taxonomy

Comment: adding entire script that fetches the Admin taxonomy

Comment: Why don't you change `$to = get_option( 'admin_email' );` to `$to = 'esorj11@gmail.com';`?

Comment: I explained in above, the theme allows to add multiple agents and those agents default to multiple properties. Right now I have it set to admin but want emails to go to the agent listed on the property